# OpenCV4Android error Stitcher mode, plane panorama

Tags: java, opencv, android

I want to stitch few images, but I need no sphere stitching, only 2d (flat, plane, sorry for my English). And what I tried:

```
Stitcher::Mode mode;
    mode = Stitcher::SCANS;
    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(mode, true);
```

I have error:

```
Error:(50) undefined reference to `cv::Stitcher::create(cv::Stitcher::Mode, bool)'
```

But     `Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();`is work, but panorama is spherical, not plane.

Comment: which OpenCV version are you using ?

Comment: 3.4.0 version, last version from site